# How can a variable be assigned to a UIInteraction in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsobject, uicontextmenuinteraction

**Why do I need variables?** Because upon 2 different long presses in the cell, there are 2 images  that need to be called in `func contextMenuInteraction`

Below is my code, where I assign a variable to each long press interaction. I get error `Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

//In scope

```
var dd : UIInteraction!
var cc : UIInteraction!
@IBOutlet weak var immy: UIImageView!
```

//In override func awakeFromNib() and an objC long press function respectively

```
immy.addInteraction(dd) // (this is in the override nib)
self.like.addInteraction(self.cc) //(this is in the @objc func didLongPress())
```

Below is the `func ContextMenuInteraction` where the 2 interactions get called

```
    func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: {
        
        if self.dd as! NSObject == interaction {
            if let unwrappedImage = self.immy.image {
                return ImagePreviewController(image:unwrappedImage)
                
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
          // put dd stuff here
        } else if self.cc as! NSObject == interaction {
          // put cc stuff here
            let image3 = UIImage(named:"ring-309550-2.png")

            if let unwrappedImage1 = image3 {
                return ImagePreviewController(image:unwrappedImage1)
                
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }

        }
        else {
                      return nil
                  }
            })
            }
```

Where does the error unexpected found nil occur - In this line:

```
immy.addInteraction(dd)
```

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete because it doesn't show the declaration for `immy`. Also, you aren't specifying where the fatal error is happening.

Comment: Sorry, just added those. immy is just a `UIImageView` outlet. Line where error occurred is `immy.addInteraction(dd)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this has been solved (not by me - someone on reddit)

```
// scope
var dd: UIContextMenuInteraction
var cc: UIContextMenuInteraction
// inside init()
self.dd = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
self.cc = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
// downstream
image1.addInteraction(dd)
image2.addinteraction(cc)

// inside contextMenuInteraction()
if self.dd == interaction {
...
} else if self.cc == interaction {
...
}
```